# Psfragfig conflict with bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, shell-escape, psfrag

I have a problem using `psfragfig` and `\bibliopraphy`. When I don't include the biblio-fille via `\bibliography(biblio)` the command `\psfragfig` works well. Once I apply `\bibliography(biblio)` I can read in the log-file the warning:

```
"Execution failed during process: latex -shell-escape -output-format=dvi -output-directory="./graphics/pulsesQP/" -interaction=batchmode "pulsesQP-pstool.tex"This warning occurred"
```

and `psfragfig` doesn't work. See shortcuts:

[image]

I use TeXstudio 2.8.4 (hg 4683+:c51d233ca5af+) on Win7

The relevant code:

```
% !TeX document-id = {5b2b92d7-fe32-4c39-a0bb-57c405d53a65}
\documentclass[twocolumn, showpacs, showkeys, amsmath, amssymb, superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{pstool}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
citation here: \cite{cit1}.
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \psfragfig*[width=0.89\linewidth]{./graphics/pulsesQP/pulsesQP}{
        \psfrag{aa}{(a)}
        \psfrag{vinj}{$V_{inj}$}
        \psfrag{tinj}{$\tau_{inj}$}
        \psfrag{ttot}{$\tau_{tot}$}
        }
    \end{minipage}
    \label{fig_timedomain}
    \caption{bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla}
\end{figure}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

I am new to Stack Exchange and I have not found any possibility to upload a minimal example revealing my problem. However i guess the conflict is connected to the `-shell-escape` option which is required by psfragfig.

Can someone help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that, when processing the file in DVI mode for converting the EPS file, the `\href@noop` macro gives problems.

A workaround is to give it a definition when in DVI mode; this shouldn't influence the typesetting, because it's relevant only for typesetting the bibliography.

```
% !TeX document-id = {5b2b92d7-fe32-4c39-a0bb-57c405d53a65}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]

\documentclass[twocolumn, showpacs, showkeys, amsmath, amssymb, superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{pstool}
\usepackage{ifpdf}

\ifpdf\else
  % give \href@noop the definition it is given in the .bbl file
  \makeatletter\providecommand\href@noop{\@secondoftwo}\makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
citation here: \cite{cit1}.
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \psfragfig*[width=0.89\linewidth]{./graphics/pulsesQP/pulsesQP}{
        \psfrag{aa}{(a)}
        \psfrag{vinj}{$V_{inj}$}
        \psfrag{tinj}{$\tau_{inj}$}
        \psfrag{ttot}{$\tau_{tot}$}
        }
    \end{minipage}
    \label{fig_timedomain}
    \caption{bla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla}
\end{figure}

\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```